# Room (SQL) query to get results ordered by today first, tomorrow second and all the rest

Tags: android, sql, android-room

How can i retrieve results sorted in the following order: today first, tomorrow second and all the rest in decs order? I'm using Jetpack's Room for Android. So far I get this `SELECT * FROM LocalCreatedWorkout ORDER BY date ASC` but this query is sorting entries in ascending order only.

Comment: Just use `ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: There entries which have later date then tomorrow and i want today first, tomorrow second, and all the rest in desc order

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use `CASE WHEN` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN date(LocalCreatedWorkout) = date('now') THEN 1 
   WHEN date(LocalCreatedWorkout) = date('now','+1 day') THEN 2
   ELSE 3 END ASC, LocalCreatedWorkout DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am wondering can I sort each case individually?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, what do you mean?